# Azure ARM Linux VM Public IP and Docker

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I've a simple problem that I provisioned a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM with all of its default components. I **ssh** into the machine, installed Docker and expose a web app container at the port 80 where a simple static web app is running. But the problem is I can't access the application from the public ip address in the browser that has been created as a separate resource with ARM model. I also assigned a named DNS but could not work :(. I have a stand alone VM.

I previously tried Docker on Ubuntu Server Azure service where I need to configure VM's endpoints in the classical way and the same application was up and running. But how do I do that in a stand alone Ubuntu VM using ARM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ARM you need to configure Network Security Groups, instead of Endpoints.
You would want to allow traffic on port 80 to the VM. Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg) to the documentation. And link to a guide on how to do that with [Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal).